# How do i access the variable which is computed inside a function in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i compute this value in the get user function

```
getUser() {
    
     final studentsc=dsa.get('courseName').toString().toLowerCase().split(" ").join() +"student";
    
   }
```

i want to access its value in the widget tree

```
body:Container{ child: StreamBuilder(
 stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("**value of studentsc**").orderBy("num").snapshots(),}
```

how do i do it? do i have to use callback?

Comment: The most straightforward way for a function to provide a value to its caller is to *return* a value: `String getUser() { final students = ...; return students; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the function should return a value as the name of the function also suggests get user.

You can do something like this:

```
getUser() {
    
    return dsa.get('courseName').toString().toLowerCase().split(" ").join() + "student";
}
```

Then you can use this in your widget tree as:

```
body:Container{
    child: StreamBuilder(stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(getUser()).orderBy("num").snapshots(),
}
```